# ": No such file or directory" when file exists

Tags: unix, ksh

I'm having some problems with some code, it's saying that a file does not exist, when I know that it does. The code is as follows:

```sh
#! /bin/ksh
echo "Enter a file name"
read fileName
if [ -e $fileName ];then
    less -M $fileName
    gedit $fileName
else
    echo "$fileName is not a file"
fi
```

I've almost certainly missed something blindingly obvious... I just wish I knew what it was. Anyway, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're checking that a file exists, not that it's not a directory, and not that it's readable or writable.  I'm also unclear what this would do given a symlink that points to nothing.  Please also include the exact error message, and ideally, which command prompted it.  Finally, does the filename you input include any white-space or shell meta-characters?

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for your response. So you're saying that I need a new command in place of the -e? With regards to the error, the error received was: ": No such file or directory" and appears after the file name has been entered without white space characters, e.g. owen.txt Thanks again

Comment: Use `-f` to test for a plain file (or symlink pointing at a file), as opposed to a directory `-d`, block device `-b`, character device `c`, symlink `-L` or `-h`, FIFO (`-p`, mnemonic 'named Pipe'), etc.  Use `-s` to test for a non-empty file.

Comment: It looks at though its the 'less $fileName' part that isn't working. Have I perhaps got the syntax wrong?

Comment: The thing that puzzles me is the quoted error message. Why is the message not quoting the file name? I wonder if you're somehow entering a carriage return (`\r`) and the name being stored is `xyz\r` instead of just `xyz`, so when the error message is printed, the `\r` wipes out the program name and file name and just the error message is left. Are you feeding this script with names from a file that came from Windows? Have you done anything funny with your terminal settings? Have you tried `echo "$fileName" | od -c` to see exactly what file name is being given? Have you tried quoting the name?

Comment: Looks like you are feeding in a carriage return at the end of your input, while the script expects a Unix line feed only.  Are you connecting from a misconfigured terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two options here:

1. A typo in the the variable name
2. Pressing Enter without a file name.

Either way this can be resolved by adding `set -u` to the top of the script,
or by using parameter expansion with a test: `${...:?}`

Finally, it's better to deal with exceptions first, and try to report what actually happens.
The error message in the original script is far removed from the actual test, and does not reflect what the test did.  In this case, it's better to let the system tell what's wrong.

Below is an example

```sh
#! /bin/ksh
echo "Enter a file name"
read fileName && [[ -e ${fileName:?} ]] || exit

less -M ${fileName:?} || exit
gedit ${fileName:?}
```